# Swagger UI: pass custom Authorization header

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle and Swagger on an ASP.NET Web API. I'm trying to find a way to pass an Authorization header containing a Bearer token through Swagger UI. I've been searching around, but all the answers seem to point at [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#custom-header-parameters---for-basic-auth-etc) link.

However, this assumes that the content of the header is known upfront. I really need a way to change the header within Swagger UI (right before hitting the 'Try it out!' button), because the Bearer token expires every hour. Something similar to the way Postman allows you to add headers.

It seems like such a ridiculously simple problem, but what is the answer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We ran into the same problem on our project. I also wanted to add the header parameters to the Swagger UI website. This is how we did it:

**1. Define an OperationFilter class**
OperationFilters are executed on every API operation every time you build Swagger. According to your code, operations will be checked according to your filters. In this example, we make the header parameter required on every operation, but make it optional on operations that have the AllowAnonymous attribute.

```cs
    public class AddAuthorizationHeader : IOperationFilter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds an authorization header to the given operation in Swagger.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operation">The Swashbuckle operation.</param>
        /// <param name="schemaRegistry">The Swashbuckle schema registry.</param>
        /// <param name="apiDescription">The Swashbuckle api description.</param>
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (operation == null) return;

            if (operation.parameters == null)
            {
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
            }

            var parameter = new Parameter
            {
                description = "The authorization token",
                @in = "header",
                name = "Authorization",
                required = true,
                type = "string"
            };

            if (apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
            {
                parameter.required = false;
            }

            operation.parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
    }
```

**2. Tell Swagger to use this OperationFilter**
In the SwaggerConfig, just add that the operation filter should be used as follows:

```cs
    c.OperationFilter<AddAuthorizationHeader>();
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: It appears that the latest version of Swashbuckle changed the Operation class to remove the parameter filter class?  Any thoughts?

Comment: if i create that filter all my actions ask for it? how can i exclude the controller actions do not require it?

Comment: @D.B Once you've decorated controller actions with [AllowAnonymous] for actions you don't want auth to apply, update "AddAuthorizationHeader" to only add parameter where NOT [AllowAnonymous]. Pseduo: If !apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()) then operation.parameters.Add(parameter);

Comment: thi worked for me thanks..will u plz tell me how to show 'Authorization'  section on swagger ui for specific APIs only ?

Answer (score 8):

Create a new operation filter that implements `IOperationFilter`.

```cs
public class AuthorizationHeaderOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an authorization header to the given operation in Swagger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation">The Swashbuckle operation.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The Swashbuckle operation filter context.</param>
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
        {
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();
        }

        var authorizeAttributes = context.ApiDescription
            .ControllerAttributes()
            .Union(context.ApiDescription.ActionAttributes())
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>();
        var allowAnonymousAttributes = context.ApiDescription.ActionAttributes().OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>();

        if (!authorizeAttributes.Any() && !allowAnonymousAttributes.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var parameter = new NonBodyParameter
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = "header",
            Description = "The bearer token",
            Required = true,
            Type = "string"
        };

        operation.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
}
```

Configure the service in your `Startup.cs` file.

```cs
        services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderOperationFilter>();
        });
```

Comment: This is the way to make it work with .NET Core 2.x and Swashbuckle 4.x. +1 for NonBodyParameter which appeared on none of the other examples on StackOverflow on this topic!

Comment: Note that for Swashbuckle 5 you no longer use a `IOperationFilter` for this and now configure it with  `AddSecurityDefinition`.

Comment: Is a NonBodyParameter in an example method like the one above in still useful if other non-auth header parameters are wanted Swashbuckle 5 ?

Comment: Yes, I guess it would be useful for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in different ways depending on how you collect the `Authorization` header and whether you want the code to handle everything or if you want the user to be able to enter what ever `Authorization` header they want.

When I first tried this, I was able to show an `Authorization` header text in each endpoint's parameter field area where a user could type in an `Authorization` header but that was not what I wanted.

In my situation, I had to send a request to the `/token` endpoint with the user's cookie in order to get a valid `Authorization` token. So I did a mix of things to achieve this.

First in `SwaggerConfig.cs` I uncommented `c.BasicAuth()` to get the basic auth scheme into the API schema and I also injected a custom `index.html` page where I inserted an AJAX request in order to grab the `Authorization` token, using the user's cookie (`index.html` code shown below):

```
public static void Register() {

    System.Reflection.Assembly thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c => {
                    ...

                    c.BasicAuth("basic").Description("Bearer Token Authentication");

                    ...
                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c => {
                    ...

                    c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "YourNamespace.index.html");

                    ...
                });
}
```

Then head [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/v5.2.1/Swashbuckle.Core/SwaggerUi/CustomAssets/index.html) to download the swashbuckle `index.html` which we will customize to insert an `Authorization` header.

Below I simply make an AJAX call to my `/token` endpoint with a valid cookie, get the `Authorization` token, and give it to swagger to use with `window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add()`:

```
...

function log() {
  if ('console' in window) {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  }
}

$.ajax({
    url: url + 'token'
  , type: 'POST'
  , data: { 'grant_type': 'CustomCookie' }
  , contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  , async: true
  , timeout: 60000
  , cache: false
  , success: function(response) {
        console.log('Token: ' + response['token_type'] + ' ' + response['access_token']);
        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", response['token_type'] + ' ' + response['access_token'], "header"));
    }
  , error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log('Status: ' + status + '. Error: ' + error + '.');
    }
});
```

I removed a few things from the AJAX call to make it more simple and obviously your implementation will probably be different depending on how you gather your `Authorization` token and stuff but that gives you an idea. If you have any specific issues or questions, let me know.

*Edit: Did not notice you actually did want the user to type in their `Authorization` header. In that case it is very easy. I used [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/501#issuecomment-143254123) post. Simply created the following class to do the work:

```
public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter {

    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription) {
        if (operation.parameters == null) {
            operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        }

        operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter {
            name = "Foo-Header",
            @in = "header",
            type = "string",
            required = true
        });
    }
}
```

Then added the class to my `SwaggerConfig` like so:

```
...
c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm interested in the first thing you mention; i.e. "When I first tried this, I was able to show an Authorization header text in each endpoint's parameter field area where a user could type in an Authorization header". How did you do this? As mentioned in the question, I want the user to type the Authorization header, I don't want the authorization header to be automatically filled in.

Comment: @fikkatra Sorry, not sure how I missed that. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

In Swashbuckle 5 this is done in `Startup.cs` with the following file.

```cs
// Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = "bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "bearerAuth" }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
});
```